# how to fill join table?

Tags: mysql, join

i'm new to mySQL. i have created a join table from two tables:

```
students
===============================
id(auto)
name

homeworks
===============================
id(auto)
description

students_homeworks
===============================
idStudentHomework(auto)
idStudent
idHomework
```

a student should fill a form in my website and provide his name and homework description. as far as i know, i sould then query the database in my php code and INSERT student.name and homework.description to respective tables.
but how should i fill the students_homeworks table?
should i query the two tables again and find the IDs and then fill the join table?
(i googled it but just found how to create join tables and SQL JOIN command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. insert into student(name) values ('john')
2. select max(id) from student
3. insert into homeworks(description) values ('maths')
4. select max(id) from homeworks
5. insert into students_homeworks (idStudent, idHomework) values(1, 1)
```

Comment: thanks juergen but i don't get the values(1,1). shouldn't i store the max(id)s in variables and do values($id1,$id2) ?

Comment: it seems a little 'not optimized'. is it the standard way? or a newbe way for me?

Comment: In PHP you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID` instead of `select max(id)`. In other programming languages you have other possibilities sometimes. In `C#` for instance you can get the inserted id as output after your insert.

Answer (score 2):

If student & homework ids are autoincrement, you can use a function [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)
 to determine the id of previously inserted record.

Answer (score 0):

If the homework description is a textbox filled in by the users. There is no need to create a separate table for it.

You only create a separate homework description if there is fixed value (for example, a dropdownlist) for users.

Comment: thanks sel, but actually i have 8 tables for homework and student details. i simplified it here